# Can we say "How much guitar do you play a day?"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, usage, spoken-english

In my experience, people can say sentences like:

> "How much guitar do you play a day?"

instead of:

> "How much do you play guitar a day?"

Do you think they are interchangeable? I think so.

Answer (score 1):

How much guitar.... is grammatical.  I think it's analogous to this transitive:

> How much food do you eat each day?

You eat how much food per day?

> How much distance do you travel each day?
>
> How much tennis do you play each week?
>
> How much beer do you brew each day?
>
> How much crime do you see each year?

P.S. Does the question **How much guitar do you play each week?** mean "How often do you play?"

Not necessarily. The person you've asked that question could reply "10 hours a week" or "every day".

P.P.S. In the comment I've given an attestation of a different version of the question: a fan asks a guitarist how much guitar he plays on a particular album. There the phrase means, "How much of the guitar playing on the album saw you on the guitar? What portion of it was you?"

And here's [another](https://ethaniverson.com/interviews/interview-with-marc-andre-hamelin/) with the same meaning as OP's original example:

> How much piano do you play before a concert?

Comment: Good answer. Minor point: I'd likely be more inclined to ask, "How **far** do you travel..." (as opposed to "How **much distance** do you travel...").

Comment: You and me both. But **how much distance** is idiomatic. *How much distance does the aeroplane cover in 40 minutes?*

Comment: Thanks. Can I say these two for meaning "How often do you play guitar?"? --------> **"How much guitar do you play?"** and **"How much do you play guitar?"**

Comment: The person you've asked might say "10 hours a week" or "every day".  The question is an imprecise one because of the way in which **guitar** has been cast as something quantifiable. So it doesn't equate simply to **how often**.

Comment: You can certainly say **How much guitar do you play a day** but guitar players might look at you a bit strangely if you did. **How much music do you listen to?** would be much easier on the ear.

Comment: @Ronald Sole:  It's idiomatic this side of the Atlantic. Check it out.  
  http://ads.guitarworld.com/dear-guitar-hero-dave-wyndorf

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I could show you some jolly funny ads from this side of the pond as well - although I've no doubt that idiom and expressions are particular to different regions and culures.

Comment: @Ronald Sole: Righto. We don't say **jolly fun** here, and I am looking at you a bit strangely as a result.

Comment: As the lady wrote: **For what do we live, but to make sport for our neighbours, and laugh at them in our turn?**

Comment: I have no problem with _"How much guitar do you play?”_ but I think it rings a little odd when we add the “a day” part: _"How much guitar do you play a day?”_ That said, I can think of conversations that could lead to such a question, for example: Musician: _I practice my guitar daily_. Me: _Really? How much guitar do you play each day?_

Comment: @J.R.We do consult our "ear" when we hear a phrase and judge whether it is idiomatic, and you guys are certainly entitled to your opinions that it is strange, but I've heard this phrase (and others like it) very often, and it is well-attested.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - I noticed that none of your examples contain "a day", either. You and I keep changing _a_ to _each_. Maybe that's part of the "oddity" with the O.P.'s originals. Interestingly enough, there's nothing ungrammatical about using "a day" instead of "each day," but I think it just reads a little strangely when used in a standalone question for some reason. Yet I can easily imagine myself asking a coworker: "How much water a day do you drink?"

Comment: @J.R. I wasn't paying much attention to that part of the sentence. I understood the focus of the question to be the phrase **how much guitar**.  I see nothing wrong with **a day**. It is idiomatic.  **How much piano do you play {each, a, per} day?**

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Just to be clear, we are in agreement on all of this. I never thought "how much guitar" was problematic, and we both agree that "{each, a, per} day" is normal English, too.